# How to get the message of exception in Behat test

Tags: symfony, behat

I'm new to behat 3, and I use it with symfony2 extensions, and all works well, but I need to know the message of thrown exception during my test. Let suppose that I want to develop simple blog, so I need to list all posts then I wrote a feature and one following scenario:

```
Feature: Browse posts
In order to browse all posts on the site
As a Visitor on the site
I need a site which shows list of all posts

Scenario: Listing all posts
Given I am on "/post"
And The database is clean
And There are following posts:
| title                       | content                     |
| Testowy tytuł posta         | Testowa treść posta         |
| Testowy tytuł posta numer 2 | Testowa treść posta numer 2 |
Then the response status code should be 200
Then I should see "All posts" in the "title" element
And I should see "Listing all posts"
And I should see "Testowy tytuł posta"
```

I was implement needed snippets and all tests passes. Ok this time I need to view blog post with slug in url so I append the following scenario to the above feature:

```
Scenario: View one post by slug
Given I am on "/post/testowy-tytul-posta"
Then the response status code should be 200
Then I should see "Testowy tytuł posta" in the "title" element
And I should see "Testowa treść posta"
```

At this moment I don't have the slug field in the entity and test should not pass and it work, but the output from console is like the following:

```
Scenario: View one post by slug                                  # src/MyVendor/BlogBundle/Features/blog/listing_posts.feature:18
Given I am on "/post/testowy-tytul-posta"                      # MyVendor\BlogBundle\Features\Context\FeatureContext::visit()
Then the response status code should be 200                    # MyVendor\BlogBundle\Features\Context\FeatureContext::assertResponseStatus()
  Current response status code is 500, but 200 expected. (Behat\Mink\Exception\ExpectationException)
Then I should see "Testowy tytuł posta" in the "title" element # MyVendor\BlogBundle\Features\Context\FeatureContext::assertElementContainsText()
And I should see "Testowa treść posta"
```

The line:

```
Current response status code is 500, but 200 expected
```

doesn't tell me what was wrong, when I run the behat command with -v option (which increase verbosity) it gives me the following outuput:

```
Scenario: View one post by slug                                  # src/MyVendor/BlogBundle/Features/blog/listing_posts.feature:18
Given I am on "/post/testowy-tytul-posta"                      # MyVendor\BlogBundle\Features\Context\FeatureContext::visit()
Then the response status code should be 200                    # MyVendor\BlogBundle\Features\Context\FeatureContext::assertResponseStatus()
  Current response status code is 500, but 200 expected.

  +--[ HTTP/1.1 500 | http://localhost/post/testowy-tytul-posta | KernelDriver ]
  |
  |  <body>
  |          <div id="content">
  |              <div class="header clear-fix">
  |                  <div class="header-logo">
  |                      <img src="data:image/png;base64,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...
  |
Then I should see "Testowy tytuł posta" in the "title" element # MyVendor\BlogBundle\Features\Context\FeatureContext::assertElementContainsText()
And I should see "Testowa treść posta"                         # MyVendor\BlogB
```

which looks like limited and not show all of the response content. It will be very helpful if there  is an option which takes only the exception message - in that case:

```
Entity 'MyVendor\BlogBundle\Entity\Post' has no field 'slug'. You can therefore not call 'findOneBySlug' on the entities' repository
```

and give it to the output instead of resposne.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I need to do is add to behat.yml the following line under Behat\MinkExtensio:

```
[...]
Behat\MinkExtension:
    show_auto: true
    show_cmd: firefox %s
[...]
```

This will stop the test on the failing step and open browser with the given result.